# How can i count how many zeros will there be in the answer to an equation and said number that is followed by the zeros

Tags: c#, automation

```
double numone = Console.ReadLine();
double numtwo = Console.ReadLine();
double answer = numtwo * numone;
Console.WriteLine($"{numone} multiplied by {numtwo} is {answer}");
```

Now let's assume numone is 30 Trillion and numtwo is 3 Billion, the answer will be 9+E22, but i also want to make it say afterwards "That's (Number) followed by (NumOfZeros) zeros!", How could i make it automatically retrieve the number and amount of zeros followed after it and then print them?
Now see i want to count ONLY the zeros FOLLOWED by the number, so lets say the number is 90900 i want it to say 2 zeros, not 3. I have a vague idea of how to make it count zeros but not a single idea how to count ONLY the zeros following the number and the number before the following the zeros. Basically have it reset NumOfZeros to 0 if it sees a non zero number after a 0 and have it also get the numbers before the first 0 it didnt reset on.

Comment: convert to string. reverse. count zeros until you get a non-zero.

Comment: @LLSv2.0 oh ok, but how do i go about making it count the zeros (i had a vague idea because i know how to do it python, not in c#) and how do i print the number after the last zero?

Comment: By the way, when you get around to parsing the strings that `Console.ReadLine` returns into `doubles` (the code you show won't compile).  Consider using `double.TryParse` rather than `Convert.ToDouble` or `double.Parse`.  `TryParse` will return `true` or `false` depending on the success or failure of the parsing.  The other two will throw exceptions.  A user entering incorrect data can hardly be considered *exceptional*

Answer (score 0):

You can use `string.LastIndexOfAny()`.

First, declare a `char` array with all the numbers except zero. This is, of course, assuming that the user input is strictly numbers. Otherwise you'll need more error checking beforehand.

```
var nonZero = new char[] { '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9' };
var strNum = "90900";

// Gets the index of the last non-zero number
var lastNumIndex = strNum.LastIndexOfAny(nonZero);
if (lastNumIndex < strNum.Length - 1)
{
    // If there are zeros after that last non-zero
    var numZeros = strNum.Length - 1 - lastNumIndex;
    Console.WriteLine("Zeros: {0}", numZeros);
}
else
{
    // There are no trailing zeroes
    Console.WriteLine("No trailing zeroes");
}
```

### Option 2

A different approach

```
var strNum = "90900";
var count = 0;

foreach (var num in strNum)
{
    count++;
    if (!Equals(num, '0'))
    {
        count = 0;
    }
}

Console.WriteLine(count);
```

Comment: That worked but, how do i also make it tell me the number before the first zero it did not reset on

Comment: Give it a try. Then if you can't still figure it out please post a new question.